Find the volume of the solid inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2-2ay=0$ and between the plane $z=0$ and the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2.$
Find the volume of the solid inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2-2ay=0$ and between the plane $z=0$ and the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2.$
I tried solving this problem as follows:
Equation of the cylinder $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2.$ Now, if we are able to find the volume $V$ between the plane $z=0$ and $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$ then the required volume is $2V.$
Let $E=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3: (x,y)\in D\text{ and } 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\},$ where $D$ is the disk $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2.$
The cylinder intersects the cone at $z^2=2ay\implies z=\pm\sqrt{2ay}.$
To find $V$ we note that, $V=\int\int\int_EdV=\int\int_D\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{2ay}}dzdA=\int\int_D\sqrt{2ay}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dA.$

From here, I thought that it would be best to convert the integral above to polar coordinates. The parameterization  for the cyclinder is given by $x=r\cos t$ and $y=a+r\sin t$ where, $t\in [0,2\pi]$ and $0\leq r\leq a.$ So, the integral becomes $V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^ar\sqrt{2a(a+r\sin t)}-r\sqrt{r^2\cos^2 t+r^2\sin ^2t+a^2+2ar\sin t}drdt=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^ar\sqrt{2a(a+r\sin t)}-r\sqrt{r^2+a^2+2ar\sin t}drdt.$
However, the above integral looks quite complicated. I have no idea how to proceed further.

Hint:
Try with cylindrical coordinates: the cylinder $x^2+y^2-2ay=0$ becomes $r^2-2ar\sin\theta=0$, or $r=2a\sin\theta$, for the upper half of the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$ the equation is $z=r$, now the domain $D$ is $\{(r,\theta):0\le r\le 2a\sin\theta,0\le \theta\le \pi\}$
\begin{align*}
V&=\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2a\sin\theta}(r-0)r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta
\end{align*}

But I used cylindrical coordinates as well? That's strange.

@ThomasFinley True, but not the same cylindrical coordinates. You've used the cylinder's axis for the $z$-axis, while this simpler setup uses the cone's. Your setup is still correct though. You can proceed with the $r$-integral by Euler sub and partial fraction expansion. The subsequent $\theta$-integral is a mess of trig expressions plus a few log-trig terms, but it supposedly has an elementary antiderivative acc. to Mathematica.
